# parse xml like document with regex

Tags: python, xml, regex

I have a file that has many xml-like elements such as this one:

```
<document docid=1>
Preliminary Report-International Algebraic Language
Perlis, A. J. & Samelson,K.
CACM December, 1958
</document>
```

I need to parse the docid and the text. What's a suitable regular expression for that?

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
collectionText = open('documents.txt').read()
docsPattern = r'<document docid=(\d+)>(.)*</document>'
docTuples = re.findall(docsPattern, collectionText)
```

EDIT: I've modified the pattern like this:

```
<document docid=(\d+)>(.*)</document>
```

This matches the whole document unfortunately not the individual document elements.

EDIT2: The correct implementation from Ahmad's and Acorn's answer is:

```
collectionText = open('documents.txt').read()
docsPattern = r'<document docid=(\d+)>(.*?)</document>'
docTuples = re.findall(docsPattern, collectionText, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: XML and Regex is two words I hate hearing together.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper, in general, you're right. But if it's XML-like format with known structure, regular expressions might be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is greedy, so if you have multiple `<document>` elements it will end up matching all of them.

You can make it non-greedy by using `.*?`, which means "match zero or more characters, as few as possible." The updated pattern is:

```
<document docid=(\d+)>(.*?)</document>
```

Comment: Well spotted. This doesn't solve the problem of the expression needing to match over multiple lines though.

Comment: @Acorn yeah I missed that, thinking the OP had that covered because it "matches the whole document." Good point though :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `DOTALL` option with your regular expression so that it will match over multiple lines (by default `.` will not match newline characters).

Also note the comments regarding greediness in Ahmad's answer.

```py
import re

text = '''<document docid=1>
Preliminary Report-International Algebraic Language
Perlis, A. J. & Samelson,K.
CACM December, 1958
</document>'''

pattern = r'<document docid=(\d+)>(.*?)</document>'
print re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)
```

---

In general, regular expressions are not suitable for parsing XML/HTML.

See:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

You want to use a parser like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de).

Comment: this isn't XML, just similar. I only need the regex for this one file

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for .net "xml-like" structure just FYI...

```
<([^<>]+)>([^<>]+)<(\/[^<>]+)>
```